# Java Script - add/create a new column in CSV file

Tags: javascript, export-to-csv, addition

I have system with employees data.
In this system I have field called Manager where is Last Name, First Name USER ID inside only this one field.

I try to export the data to CSV file and use below script to have First Name Last Name in one
column and USER ID of Manager in the new one.
But the code doesn't work, any idea how to fix it to work properly?

Below the code I try to use:

```
// employee

var i, name, col;
for (i = 0; i < headers.length+1; i++) {

  name = toStr(headers[i]);
  col = obj.get(name);

  switch (name) {
   case 'MANAGER':
    if (col) {
     columns[i] = col.get('FIRSTNAME') +" "+ col.get('LASTNAME');
     columns[headers.length+1] = col.get('USERID');

    } else {
     columns[i] = 'NO_MANAGER';
    }
    break;

  default:
   columns[i] = col;
  }
 }
```

CSV File Columns:

```
HOW IT IS
USER ID FIRSTNAME LASTNAME MANAGER
12345   JOHN      SMITH    BOND, JAMES 45678

HOW I WANT:
USERID FIRSTNAME LASTNAME MANAGER    MANAGERID
12345  JOHN      SMITH    JAMES BOND 45678
```

Comment: You need to add more context to this piece of code. We don't know what is the data structure, headers, obj, columns...

With this said, I found strange that you do a get here `col = obj.get(name);` and after you do another get in col `col.get('USERID')`

Comment: I added the screenshot of CSV file with the explanation.
These fields (headers) are from my database and then I would like to map it by script to have First Name and Last Name of Manager in one column and USER ID of Manager in the new column

Comment: the CSV is invalid.